# How can I render a local json spec in swagger in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle, openapi

I have a json spec(webapi.json) and would like to render the same using swashbuckle. Is there any way to achieve this?

My configure method looks like this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render any swagger spec just by passing it as a param in the URL

Here is an example:
http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1

If you already have a json spec(webapi.json) there is no need to add swashbuckle to your project.

Comment: Thanks @Helder Sepulveda